selenium not opening new url
In the code below, it should go to 3 URLs, but it only goes to 1. How can I solve it? Can you help me?
myURLs = ["https://google.com", "https://x.com", "https://cnn.com"]

I tried it, it opens a new tab, but the URL does not go. I need it on the same page. The processes are finished on url1, I need to go to url2 on the same page.
chrome_driver_path = 'E:/chromedriver.exe'
portable_chrome_path = 'E:/chromeX1/GoogleChromePortable.exe'
user_data_dir = 'E:/chromeX1/data' 

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={user_data_dir}')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')  
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')  
options.binary_location = portable_chrome_path

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver_path), options=options)

def url1():
    url = 'https://google.com'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(15)

def url2():
    url = 'https://x.com'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(15)

def url3():
    url = 'https://cnn.com'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(15)

url1()
url2()
url3()

time.sleep(555)

#driver.quit()


It doesn't work this way, so instead pass new urls to the same driver function using driver.get(url), which will redirect it to the next page.
Here's an example:
urls_list=[url1,url2,url3]
def call_urls(urls_list):
driver.get(urls_list[0])
##Do something ##
time.sleep(10)
driver.get(urls_list[1])
##Do something ##
time.sleep(10)

driver.quit() #At last, once all jobs for the urls are executed.

Hope it helps:)
